# using autentication with torsocks --address

Tags: configuration, security, socks, torsocks, tor-install

On Linux, I noticed I can run `torsocks` by specifying `--address` so that it connects to another computer and use that computer's tor connection, e.g downloading a file over tor:

```
torsocks --address my.second.server.ip wget site1234567899.onion/example.html
```

On that second computer I can whitelist the 1st computer IP so it can connect to this second computer. I do that by this line in **torrc**:

```
SOCKSPolicy accept my.first.server.ip
```

But can I do this by a password intead of IP filtering ? There are many password options in **torrc** and **torsocks.conf**, not sure which one to use (if any).